# Month not working as expected in HIVE

Tags: hive

Invalid Month in output

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('Jul/21/2016 11:37:00 AM','MMM/DD/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa'))  from table
```

getting

```
2016-01-21 11:37:00
```

expecting 
    2016-07-21 11:37:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dd` for days (in lowercase, instead of uppercase):

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('Jul/21/2016 11:37:00 AM','MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa')) from table

2016-07-21 11:37:00
```

Comment: Do we have any docs supporting  that we have to use dd in place of DD for month and also month is getting effected in place of date when we try this 
    select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('Jul/21/2016 11:37:00 AM','MMM/DD/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa')) wrong , from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('Jul/21/2016 11:37:00 AM','MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa')) correct from table

Comment: The problem was using "DD" for the days, instead of "dd". Using MM or MMM for the months is correct. I think that since "DD" is not parsed to anything, the regex used in Hive caused the unexpected results somehow.